# magento 1.9 Catalog search result showing encoded result in other languages other than english

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I have a multi-store website with different languages

when I search the terms from other languages it gives an incorrect result with special characters.

and the URL is like this

catalogsearch/result?q=%25E9%2585%258D%25E4%25BB%25B6

does anyone know the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution,

The problem is not related to the Magento code or backend configuration
it's a server configuration.
In my .htaccess the redirection is 301

like

**#RedirectMatch 301 "/landing**

and due to the query string encoding two times.

I changed .htaccess accordingly and now it's working fine.